# Are (former Australian Prime Minister) Tony Abbott's Indian Facebook likes fake?

Tags: australia, india, tony-abbott

[image: Text below]
[Source](https://www.facebook.com/BondiHipsters/photos/a.332842453444735.76452.311976212198026/814468865282089/?type=1)

> Hey Tony brah... Hahve [sic] you been buying Facebook likes? ...
>   Either thaht [sic] of [sic] you're really popular with 18-34 year olds
>   from New Delhi.

[image: Page from Facebook discussed by the Bondi Hipsters]

Are the Facebook 'likes' Abbott has received from India real, or fake? (I'm not really concerned whether Abbott bought the likes, or whether they were fake likes from a like farm liking pages at random to make themselves look less suspicious.)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Mainstream media reports suggest the fandom is genuine.

[So, like, likable: Tony Abbott's Facebook popularity soars thanks to Narendra Modi](http://www.theage.com.au/federal-politics/political-news/so-like-likable-tony-abbotts-facebook-popularity-soars-thanks-to-narendra-modi-20141125-11tv7c.html) indicates that Indian PM Narendra Modi has a lot of facebook fans, and getting mentioned by him may have slashdotted Abbott:

> But a spokeswoman for Mr Abbott said the increased traffic was genuine
>   and that no "likes" or advertising had been purchased for the Facebook
>   page.
>
> "It is no secret that the Prime Minister hosted a number of world
>   leaders in recent times, including Indian Prime Minister Narendra
>   Modi," she said.
>
> "These visits attracted large international audiences to the Prime
>   Minister's social media channels, thus generating a spike in organic
>   engagement with the page."
>
> Earlier this month Mr Modi posted photos with Mr Abbott during his
>   visit to Australia for the G20 summit.
>
> Mr Modi has more than 25 million Facebook likes and 8.17 million
>   Twitter followers. A selfie with Mr Abbott posted to his Facebook
>   account with the a caption that read "With my friend Tony Abbott at
>   the MCG" received more than 710,000 likes and was shared more than
>   11,600 times.
>
> Other photos of the two leaders also received hundreds of thousands of
>   likes.
>
> Mr Modi is particularly popular with young Indians and has been dubbed
>   the "rock star Prime Minister".

[Tony Abbott’s Facebook popularity skyrockets all thanks to one selfie](http://www.news.com.au/technology/online/tony-abbotts-facebook-popularity-skyrockets-all-thanks-to-one-selfie/story-fnjwnhzf-1227134478482) argues that Abbott's spike in popularity coincided with a [November 18 selfie](https://www.facebook.com/narendramodi/photos/a.10150164299700165.421791.177526890164/10154915702750165/?type=1) with Modhi (note: false bottom graph)

(Note: graph is from [Tony Abbott is Mystifyingly Popular in New Delhi's Facebook Community](http://www.pedestrian.tv/news/arts-and-culture/tony-abbott-is-mystifyingly-popular-in-new-delhis-/a0fa3d74-3935-40d5-b505-d705a509db03.htm))
[image: New improved graph - y axis values not truncated]

[Tony Abbott is Mystifyingly Popular in New Delhi's Facebook Community](http://www.pedestrian.tv/news/arts-and-culture/tony-abbott-is-mystifyingly-popular-in-new-delhis-/a0fa3d74-3935-40d5-b505-d705a509db03.htm) (by Pedestrian.tv) notes that his Indian likes are still in the minority:

> Statistics gleaned from social media analysis site Social Bakers
>   indicate that somehow, even if the popular majority of Prime Minister
>   Abbott's fans are 18-34 year old New Delhi residents, his newfound New
>   Delhi fan base only accounts for 15.5% of his total audience.

[Socialbakers](http://www.socialbakers.com/facebook-pages/216342268645-tony-abbott) has looked at Tony Abbott's popularity by country:

```
Australia 287 887 fans, 72.8%
India 61 287 fans, 15.5%
United States 5 005 fans, 1.3%
```

No other country had more than 1% of his fan base.

Comment: The scale on the left of the graph is cropped.

Comment: @nic yeah, annoying. I've replaced it with a new graph.